# Compare dates fields in angularjs datepicker

Tags: angularjs, datepicker

I am trying to compare two input text fields , having datepicker angular ui attached.

The two fields are start date and end date at http://jsfiddle.net/iamkhush/8Rezs/23/.

I tried to attach this function on ng-change , but realised it wont work as datepicker doesnt allow it.

```
 $scope.datechange = function(){
     if($scope.enddt < $scope.startdt){
        $scope.enddt = '';
    };
```

I cant find out how to override the directive , if that's required. 
Also I want that the datepicker should hide when input fields are not on focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified your fiddle slightly for comparing the dates. Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9ezsJ/). The changes are:

```
$scope.$watch('startdt', function(newval, oldval){
    if($scope.enddt < $scope.startdt) {
        $scope.enddt = '';
    };
});

$scope.$watch('enddt', function(newval, oldval){
    if($scope.enddt < $scope.startdt) {
        $scope.enddt = '';
    };
});
```

Ive taken the liberty to disable the textfields as otherwise the user can enter an invalid date in the text field. Also the logic is in such a way that if you enter a startDate thats lower than the endDate and subsequently alter the startDate to be after the endDate, the endDate will be reset. IOW, the start-date controls everything. Please change as per your needs.

Also, to show/hide based on the text field, look at the dropdown directive in angular-ui. I havent included that in the fiddle, but it should be doable using a combination of dropdown and datepicker.

Comment: Hey, its working :), but I can see your code is similar to what I had experimented with. I had just checked it again, if I just use the second watch function, it doesnt work. Can you please explain me this.

Comment: The combination of the 2 $watches are so that if you change any of the  two datepickers, the other one is validated as well. What doesnt work if you just use the second function.

Comment: Well , the logic wasnt working earlier, but now it is, miraculously.

Comment: The minor edit I made was to use $scope.$watch instead of $scope.watch, which doesnt exist. That and the logic to watch both from and to dates, thats all :)

Answer (score 1):

Bit late for an answer but if u just want to compare to dates using angular ui datetime picker you can use the following directive I have created it compares to date value using moment.js. This directive requires moment.js file but you can even do without it but peronally i think moment.js is great for date function in javascript. there is you the directive which compares date is following

```
mainApp.directive("dateGreaterAndEqual", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A', // only activate on element attribute
        require: '?ngModel', // get a hold of NgModelController

        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
            if (!ngModel) return; // do nothing if no ng-model

            // watch own value and re-validate on change
            scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function () {
                validate();
            });

            // observe the other value and re-validate on change
            attrs.$observe('dateGreaterAndEqual', function (val) {
                validate();
            });

            var validate = function () {
                // values
                var dateTo = angular.isDefined(ngModel.$viewValue) === true && !_.isNull(ngModel.$viewValue) ? moment(ngModel.$viewValue).toDate() : null;
                var dateFrom = attrs.dateGreaterAndEqual !== "" ? moment(attrs.dateGreaterAndEqual.replace('"', '').replace('\\', '').replace('"', '')).toDate() : null;
                //passing date with braces around it causes and issue therfore we need to use replace

            };
        }
    }

});
```

dateTo and dateFrom is the value you need. you need following html markup to use it

```
                         <p class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" data-datepicker-popup="{{Model.DateFormat}}"
                                   ng-model="Model.ProcedureDateTo"
                                   data-is-open="openedTo" data-min-date="Model.MinDate"
                                   data-max-date="Model.MaxDate"
                                   data-datepicker-options="dateOptions" data-date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)"
                                   ng-required="false" data-close-text="{{Close}}" data-date-greater-and-equal="{{Model.ProcedureDateFrom}}" />
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="openTo($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                            </span>
                        </p>
```

The key in this line is

> data-date-greater-and-equal="{{Model.ProcedureDateFrom}}" which get passed to directive for comparison.